# Code to change the input class when the field is "required"

Tags: solspace-freeform

I am trying to figure out the code that will allow me to change the class of the input field when the field is required. I have created css that will change the field color and can't figure out how to set this up correctly in the new FreeForm composer template.

I have set this up to add "* required" on the field name:

```
<label class="field_label" {if composer:field_name != ''}for="freeform_{composer:field_name}"{/if}>
        {composer:field_label}
        {if composer:field_required}<span class="required_item" style="font-size: 0.9em"><i>* required</i></span>{/if}
</label>
```

Comment: Can you post what the HTML should look like when it's *not* required, and what it should look like when it *is* required?

Comment: I am still not getting this to work. We were able to do this before we converted the forms to Composer. Here is a link to a form that still has the old forms. [link]http://www.msj.edu/marketing/contact-us-form and here is the a link to the new form.[link] http://www.msj.edu/contact/contact-us/contact-form/ You will notice that I can't get the blue hash background to show up in the required input areas.

Answer (score 3):

Best way to do this is to add the class to a containing element like this:

```
<div  {if composer:field_required}class="required"{/if}>
    <label></label>
    <input>
</div>
```

Then target the input field with css like this:

```
.required input {
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

---

You can also use this for your "* required" copy...  Change

```
{if composer:field_required}
    <span class="required_item" style="font-size: 0.9em">
        <i>* required</i>
    </span>
{/if}
```

to

```
<span class="required_item" style="font-size: 0.9em">
    <i>* required</i>
</span>
```

And set CSS to this:

```
.required_item {
    display: none;
}
.required .required_item {
    display: block;
}
```